# Collecting values from the part-AJAX form with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

I currently have a form with a dropdown box, and when the value in the dropdown changes, a PHP file with some more form elements get loaded via jQuery's $.ajax function into the main form. However when I submit the form (using just the non-AJAX way) the values from the 'ajaxed' area of the form are not included in the $_POST values. Do you know a way of being able to include the AJAX form values when the form is submitted?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in your jquery code for the submit functionality.  Try using the live() function.

For instance

```
$("form").live(submit(function() {
   $.ajax("page.php",......
  ..........   
});
```